# What issues with future 3rd-party packages could be expected if removing unneeded Python3 core modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have an environment with some extreme constraints that require me to reduce the size of a planned Python 3.8.1 installation. The OS is not connected to the internet, and a user will never open an interactive shell or attach a debugger.

There are of course lots of ways to do this, and one of the ways I am exploring is to remove some core modules, for example `python3-email`. I am concerned that there are 3rd-party packages that future developers may include in their apps that have unused but required dependencies on core python features. For example, if `python3-email` is missing, what 3rd-party packages might not work **that one would expect too**? If a developer decides to use a logging package that contains an unreferenced `EmailLogger` class in a referenced module, it will break, simply because `import email` appears at the top.

Do package design requirements or guidelines exist that address this?

Comment: Your question is very interesting one. I never thought like that. But your purpose is only reduce the size of your software dist, what about to use Python compilers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unanswerable.

Comment: @martineau - it is unanswerable whether package design requirements or guidelines exist?

Comment: You explicitly mention needs of future developers. Who *knows* what they may need? The guideline would be "Don't touch the standard library".

Comment: Dan: @chepner comments explain the reasoning behind my own. It's all speculation on your part.

Comment: Updated the question to provide constraints on what future developers would never need.

Comment: @Dan This question is not answerable unless you provide some more details. One can assume you might refer to the fact that for example on Debian (and Ubuntu) some parts of the standard library can be left uninstalled. Is that what you mean? What is that `python3-email` you mentioned?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get to a solution. The issue was best described to me as *cascading imports*. It is possible to stop a module from being loaded, by adding an entry to `sys.modules`. For example, when importing the `asyncio` module `ssl` and `_ssl` modules will be loaded, even though they are not needed outside of ssl. This can be stopped with the following code. This can be verified both by seeing the python process is 3MB smaller, but also by using module load hooks to watch each module as it loads:

```py
import importhook
import sys
sys.modules['ssl'] = None

@importhook.on_import(importhook.ANY_MODULE)
def on_any_import(module):
    print(module.__spec__.name)
    assert module.__spec__.name not in ['ssl', '_ssl']

import asyncio
```

For my original question about 3rd-party design guidelines, some recommend placing the import statements within the class rathe that at the module level, however this is not routinely done.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question, but it is too broad to be cleanly answered here. In short, the Python standard library is expected to always be there, even though sometimes it broken up in multiple parts (Debian for example). But you say it yourself, you don't know what your requirements are since you don't know yet what *future* packages will run on this interpreter... This is impossible to answer. One thing you could do is to use something like [`modulefinder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/modulefinder.html) on the *future* code before letting it run on that constrained Python interpreter.